# Diode behaviour in a simple circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

I have tried using the formula:
\$I_d = I_s \cdot e^{V_d \over V_k}\$
where \$I_d\$ = diode current, \$V_d\$ = diode voltage and \$V_k\$ is a known and given voltage. I got nothing.

Edit: here's what I tried:

[image]

Comment: You will have to show what you tried. "I got nothing" does not suffice and will get your question closed.

Comment: yeah i did what u said. not sure how it'll help though because however much i read about the topic i cant do one single question.

Comment: Hint 1: draw the schematic larger and write down all voltages and currents you know or can easily determine. Hint 2: The diode equation gives you the current through the diode for a certain voltage across the diode. \$V_o\$ is given and it not only the output voltage but also **the voltage across a diode** so that means you can calculate...  Then use Ohm's to calculate the current through .... The sum of those currents flows through ... and .... Use the diode equation to calculate the resulting voltage. Add 3 voltages up and you know \$V_i\$.

Comment: Current flows through the path of least resistance.  At steady state, what is the equivalent resistor for the diode in parallel to the resistor? and why?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks for your hints i think i got it using the equation and the voltage on the rightmost diode's branch. than the resistive current and diode current combine at ground and go to the main and the rest is easy.

Comment: @Abel *Current flows through the path of least resistance.* So are you saying that if I connect a 1 Mohm resistor in parallel with a 1 Ohm resistor and apply a voltage across the parallel resistors, all the current will flow through the 1 Ohm resistor? It has the least resistance of the two resistors. I assure you that Ohm's law still applies which would contradict your statement.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie summary least resistance model: each infinetecimal unit of current flows through only the path of least resistance, increasing it (near infinitely until energy is dissipated). When combined with proper energy-resistance relations and movement of energy through materials, it can model many different components including resistors that are overheating.  It's a model that logically explodes against the unreality of constant resistance without flow of energy and has some interesting implications about superconductors (and how they cannot create perpetual motion machines).

Comment: More useful, and readily usable implications of the model- anything can be modeled as a "resistor" if you allow some strange functions to dictate resistance.

Comment: some more obvious implications: identically doubling cross-sectional area will halve resistance, since that area shall contain the same quantity of paths.

Comment: @Abel *summary least resistance model* Sounds overcomplicated since the excercise can be solved with Ohm's law, inversing the Shockley equation and some common sense. You should add an answer and use that model to show that it is useful so we can all learn from that. My feeling is that you cannot show a proper way to answer the question with the "least resistance model" but feel free to prove me wrong and show that I'm talking nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, let's make a mathematical closed solution. I know that this is maybe above the OP's knowledge, but I think it is important to show it.

The [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation), gives the relation between the voltage across and the current trough a diode:

$$\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_\text{D}}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\tag1$$

Where \$\text{I}_\text{D}\$ is the diode current, \$\text{I}_\text{S}\$ is the reverse bias [saturation current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_current), \$\text{V}_\text{D}\$ is the voltage across the diode, \$\text{q}\$ is the [electron charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge), \$\text{k}\$ is the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant), \$\text{T}\$ is the temperature and \$\eta\$ is the ideality factor.

---

We are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fww1HF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag2$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\left(\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\right)}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_2}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Substitute \$(3)\$ into \$(2)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_2}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\left(\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\right)}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_2}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

For the LED, let's use assume: \$\eta=1\$. And let's choose for \$\text{I}_\text{S}=3\cdot10^{-14}\space\text{A}\$ (as given in your question). Assume \$\text{V}_\text{T}:=\frac{\text{kT}}{\text{q}}=\frac{8094745087}{320435326800}\approx0.0252617\:\text{V}\$, of course (where we assumed the diode at room temperature). Then we find:

- If \$\text{R}=1000\space\Omega\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{i}\approx2.02775\space\text{V}\tag5$$
- If \$\text{R}=400\space\Omega\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{i}\approx2.03161\space\text{V}\tag6$$

---

I solved for all the knowns using [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). The code is given below.

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
q = ((1602176634/(10^9)))*10^(-19);
k = ((1380649/(10^6)))*10^(-23);
T = 20 + ((5463)/20);
Is = 3*10^(-14);
\[Eta] = 1;
R = 1000;
V2 = 675/1000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(Vi - V1))/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1),
    I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(V1 - V2))/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1), 
   I2 == Is*(Exp[(q*V2)/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1), I3 == V2/R, 
   I1 > 0 && I2 > 0 && I3 > 0 && V1 > 0 && Vi > 0}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, 
   Vi}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (3 (22499999999 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)))/
   100000000000000, 
  I2 -> (3 (-1 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)))/100000000000000, 
  I3 -> 27/40000, 
  V1 -> 27/40 + (
    8094745087 Log[22500000000 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)])/
    320435326800, 
  Vi -> 27/40 + (
    8094745087 Log[22500000000 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)])/
    160217663400}}

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={{I1 -> 0.0127418, I2 -> 0.0120668, I3 -> 0.000675, V1 -> 1.35137, 
  Vi -> 2.02775}}

In[3]:=Clear["Global`*"];
q = ((1602176634/(10^9)))*10^(-19);
k = ((1380649/(10^6)))*10^(-23);
T = 20 + ((5463)/20);
Is = 3*10^(-14);
\[Eta] = 1;
R = 400;
V2 = 675/1000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(Vi - V1))/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1),
    I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(V1 - V2))/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1), 
   I2 == Is*(Exp[(q*V2)/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1), I3 == V2/R, 
   I1 > 0 && I2 > 0 && I3 > 0 && V1 > 0 && Vi > 0}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, 
   Vi}]]

Out[3]={{I1 -> (3 (56249999999 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)))/
   100000000000000, 
  I2 -> (3 (-1 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)))/100000000000000, 
  I3 -> 27/16000, 
  V1 -> 27/40 + (
    8094745087 Log[56250000000 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)])/
    320435326800, 
  Vi -> 27/40 + (
    8094745087 Log[56250000000 + E^(216293845590/8094745087)])/
    160217663400}}

In[4]:=N[%3]

Out[4]={{I1 -> 0.0137543, I2 -> 0.0120668, I3 -> 0.0016875, V1 -> 1.35331, 
  Vi -> 2.03161}}
```

Comment: pretty sure the textbook solution would set ideality factor to 1 unless otherwise specified...

Comment: @Abel I edited my answer. Thanks for the comment, I think that you're right.

Comment: You might want to ignore the '1' factor, which allows an exactly closed form solution to be written down  with using a numerical solver. 

The difference is negligible at sensible forward currents. Using your value for Vt, I get: 

Input voltage: 2.027749963314493 for R = 1000

Input voltage: 2.031613126579359 for R = 400